# How can I set a counter to the result of a command?

Tags: macros, counters

I have a document where I would like to define a number of counters in terms of other counters.

In order to do this I've made a command that calculates the relationship between these counters.

```
\newcommand{\modifier}[1]{
 \ifthenelse{\value{#1} < 9}{-1}{
 \ifthenelse{\value{#1} < 13}{0}{
 \ifthenelse{\value{#1} < 16}{1}{2}}}
}
```

However when I attempt to use the command to set counters

```
\newcounter{strength}
\setcounter{strength}{11}
\newcounter{dexterity}
\setcounter{dexterity}{15}
\newcounter{str}    
\setcounter{str}{\modifier{strength}}
\newcounter{dex}
\setcounter{dex}{\modifier{dexterity}}
```

The compiler complains that there is no number in the second field of the `\setcounter` command.

How can I set my second counter in terms of the first one using a command?

Comment: Why don't you just set the counter within the `\ifthenelse` statements, e.g. `\ifthenelse{\value{#1} < 9}{\setcounter{str}{-1}}`?

Comment: @marmot Because I was hoping to use the new command for more than one target counter (both the `str` counter and 5 other counters).  I suppose it would work but I would end up with a ton of clutter.

Comment: Even then my proposal is only marginally more space consuming. And why would one need 5 counters with identical values?

Comment: @marmot The 6 counters would have different values.  I've expanded on the example in the question to hopefully make things clearer.  There are 12 counters total 6 of which I would like to set based on the values of the other 6.

Answer (score 8):

You need expandable tests for usage in `\setcounter`, which `\ifthenelse` isn't.

There are other solutions with `etoolbox`, but I'll present one with `expl3`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xparse}

\ExplSyntaxOn

\NewExpandableDocumentCommand{\modifier}{m}
 {
  \int_compare:nTF { \value{#1} < 9 }
   { -1 }
   {
    \int_compare:nTF { \value{#1} < 13 }
     { 0 }
     {
      \int_compare:nTF { \value{#1} < 16 }
       { 1 }
       { 2 }
     }
   }
 }
\ExplSyntaxOff

\newcounter{strength}
\newcounter{dexterity}
\newcounter{str}    
\newcounter{dex}

\begin{document}

\setcounter{strength}{11}
\setcounter{dexterity}{15}
\setcounter{str}{\modifier{strength}}
\setcounter{dex}{\modifier{dexterity}}

strength: \arabic{strength}

dexterity: \arabic{dexterity}

str: \arabic{str}

dex: \arabic{dex}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 6):

The `\ifthenelse` evaluations are not expandable. Here's a (La)TeX implementation that provides expandability:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\newcommand{\modifier}[1]{%
  \ifnum\value{#1}<9 -1
  \else\ifnum\value{#1}<13 0
  \else\ifnum\value{#1}<16 1
  \else 2
  \fi\fi\fi
}

\begin{document}

\newcounter{strength}
\setcounter{strength}{11}
\newcounter{dexterity}
\setcounter{dexterity}{15}
\newcounter{str}    
\setcounter{str}{\modifier{strength}}
\newcounter{dex}
\setcounter{dex}{\modifier{dexterity}}

strength: \thestrength

dexterity: \thedexterity

str: \thestr

dex: \thedex

\end{document}
```